# Multiple tables where there were only meant to be 2

Tags: php, html, css

I have a task-manager website where the welcome page was suposed to have 2 tables: 1 with the task that weren't complete and another with the completed ones. 
Instead of that, it creates a new table every time I add a task (completed or not).

I have tried moving some of the table code to other parts of the page.

```
<head>
    <title> Welcome!</title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div align = "right" style = " font-size:12px;"><h2>
    <p> Welcome <?php echo ' '.$login_session.'<br>'; ?>
    <a href = "logout.php"> Log out (<i> out </i>) </a></p></h2>
    </div>

    <?php $tasks = DBRead($login_session)?>
    <h1> List of tasks</h1>
<?php
    foreach($tasks as $cl){
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
        $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
        $dayoftask = $cl['completed_at'];

        if($dayoftask < $date){
            echo "
                <table width=100% border=1>
                    <tr> 
                    <td align=center>Name</td>
                    <td align=center>Description</td>
                    <td align=center>Create At</td>
                    <td align=center>Created By</td>
                    <td align=center>Completed At</td>
                    <td align=center>Edit</td>
                    <td align=center>Delete</td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td align=center>".($cl['name'])."</td>
                    <td align=center>".($cl['description'])."</td>
                    <td align=center>".($cl['created_at'])."</td>
                    <td align=center>".($cl['username'])."</td>
                    <td align=center>".($cl['completed_at'])."</td>";
?>
            <td><a href="alterar.php?id=<?=$cl['id_task']?>">&#8634;</a></td>
            <td><a href="eliminar.php?id=<?=$cl['id_task']?>" onclick="return confirm('Tem a certeza que pretende eliminar o registo?')">x</a></td>
            </tr>
<?php
            echo"</table><br>";
        }else{
            echo"<table width=100% border=1>
            <tr> 
            <td align=center>Name</td>
            <td align=center>Description</td>
            <td align=center>Create At</td>
            <td align=center>Created By</td>
            <td align=center>Completed At</td>
            <td align=center>Edit</td>
            <td align=center>Delete</td> 
            <tr>
            <td align=center>".($cl['name'])."</td>
            <td align=center>".($cl['description'])."</td>
            <td align=center>".($cl['created_at'])."</td>
            <td align=center>".($cl['username'])."</td>
            <td align=center>".($cl['completed_at'])."</td>                
            </table>";
        }
    } 
?>
    <br>
    <a href="registar.html"> <input type="button" name="" value="Create Task"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect two tables each one filled by the completed and not completed tasks, but it creates a new table for every task.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: you need to move <table> tags outside of the loop

Comment: @AkashShrivastava I already did, same results.. any sugestion as to where to?

Answer (score 0):

What Akash suggests, move the code creating the `<table>` outside of the loop, something like:

```
<h1> List of tasks</h1>
    <?php

    echo "
        <table width=100% border=1>
            <tr> 
            <td align=center>Name</td>
            <td align=center>Description</td>
            <td align=center>Create At</td>
            <td align=center>Created By</td>
            <td align=center>Completed At</td>
            <td align=center>Edit</td>
            <td align=center>Delete</td> 
            </tr>";

    foreach($tasks as $cl){
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
        $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
        $dayoftask = $cl['completed_at'];

        if($dayoftask < $date) {
            echo "<tr>
                <td align=center>".($cl['name'])."</td>
                <td align=center>".($cl['description'])."</td>
                <td align=center>".($cl['created_at'])."</td>
                <td align=center>".($cl['username'])."</td>
                <td align=center>".($cl['completed_at'])."</td>";
                ?>
                <td><a href="alterar.php?id=<?=$cl['id_task']?>">&#8634;</a></td>
                <td><a href="eliminar.php?id=<?=$cl['id_task']?>" onclick="return confirm('Tem a certeza que pretende eliminar o registo?')">x</a></td>
                </tr>
        } else {
            echo"<tr>
                <td align=center>".($cl['name'])."</td>
                <td align=center>".($cl['description'])."</td>
                <td align=center>".($cl['created_at'])."</td>
                <td align=center>".($cl['username'])."</td>
                <td align=center>".($cl['completed_at'])."</td></tr>";
        }
    } 

    <?php
        echo"</table><br>";     
    ?>
```

Comment: sounds like an HTML problem, instead of posting a screenshot can you link to a page where we can see the source code?

Comment: number of <td> dont match the number of columns in your 'else' block, try adding 2 blank <td> tags

Comment: the web page is offline

Comment: thing is.. you put in all in one table, I need to separate the completed and uncompleted and put them in separate tables

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea but you could perhaps iterate through the loop and add content to two arrays which will later be used to generate the final table

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Welcome!</title>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div align = "right" style = " font-size:12px;">
            <h2>
                <p> Welcome <?php echo $login_session . '<br>'; ?>
                    <a href="logout.php">Log out</a>
                </p>
            </h2>
        </div>

        <?php 
            $tasks = DBRead( $login_session );
        ?>
        <h1>List of tasks</h1>

        <?php

            $complete=[];
            $incomplete=[];

            foreach( $tasks as $cl ){

                date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
                $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
                $dayoftask = $cl['completed_at'];

                if( $dayoftask < $date ){

                    $complete[]="
                        <tr>
                            <td>{$cl['name']}</td>
                            <td>{$cl['description']}</td>
                            <td>{$cl['created_at']}</td>
                            <td>{$cl['username']}</td>
                            <td>{$cl['completed_at']}</td>
                            <td><a href="alterar.php?id={$cl['id_task']}">&#8634;</a></td>
                            <td><a href="eliminar.php?id={$cl['id_task']}" onclick="return confirm('Tem a certeza que pretende eliminar o registo?')">x</a></td>
                        </tr>";

                } else {

                    $incomplete[]="
                        <tr>
                            <td>{$cl['name']}</td>
                            <td>{$cl['description']}</td>
                            <td>{$cl['created_at']}</td>
                            <td>{$cl['username']}</td>
                            <td>{$cl['completed_at']}</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>";
                }
            }
        ?>


        <!-- Completed tasks -->
        <table id='complete' width='100%' border=1>
            <tr> 
                <td align=center>Name</td>
                <td align=center>Description</td>
                <td align=center>Create At</td>
                <td align=center>Created By</td>
                <td align=center>Completed At</td>
                <td align=center>Edit</td>
                <td align=center>Delete</td> 
            </tr>
            <?php
                echo implode( PHP_EOL, $complete );
            ?>
        </table>



        <!-- uncompleted tasks -->
        <table id='incomplete' width='100%' border=1>
            <tr> 
                <td align=center>Name</td>
                <td align=center>Description</td>
                <td align=center>Create At</td>
                <td align=center>Created By</td>
                <td align=center>Completed At</td>
                <td align=center>Edit</td>
                <td align=center>Delete</td> 
            </tr>
            <?php
                echo implode( PHP_EOL, $incomplete );
            ?>
        </table>

        <a href="registar.html">
            <input type="button" name="" value="Create Task" />
        </a>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, it works but the icons are out of the table... print:https://ibb.co/W3cV8SL